# how to configure dependencies play framework 1.2.5?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

i have a problem with my play application, my play can't detect module i've created.
this is my application dependencies

```
# Application dependencies

require:
    - play
    - tesModule -> tesModule 1.0
     repositories:
    - My modules:
        type:       local
        artifact:   ${application.path}/../[module]-[revision]
        contains:
           - tesModule -> *
```

after i run command `play dependencies` the command prompt told me there was missing dependencies like this

```
~
~ *****************************************************************************
~ WARNING: These dependencies are missing, your application may not work properly 
(use --verbose for details),
~
~       tesModule->tesModule 1.0
~ *****************************************************************************
~
~ Some dependencies are still missing.
~
```

my application and my module in the same folder. What's wrong with this, my play cannot detect my module, iam using java language to develop my application. Help iam new in play framework, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the module revision in your local repo

Here is an example

```
        - localModules:
            type: local
            descriptor: "${application.path}/../[module]/conf/dependencies.yml"
            artifact: "${application.path}/../[module]"
```